# mySQL Wordpress creating table from wp_usermeta.value query not working

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Working on my first WP plugin/learning SQL for a project at work.

I am using mySQL 5.5 and plan on running the following code through a $wpdb->query() function in PHP, though I am testing directly in phpMyAdmin for now.

I am trying to create a table that combines and simplifies information from the wp_usermeta table and another plugin(buddypress) to create a table that I can then pull create user reports organized by different feilds (name, location, points).

Following a coworker's advice I have made a new table to consolidate data into.

```
CREATE TABLE new_table(
user_id varchar(255),
first_name varchar(255),
last_name varchar(255),
points varchar(255),
location varchar(255)
```

which I will then update with values from the wp_usermeta table. If you don't know the user meta table looks like this:

| umeta_id | user_id | meta_key  | meta_value |

|    1     |    20   | last_name |  Doe       |

|    2     |    20   | first_name|  John      |

|    3     |    20   | points    |  500       |

|    4     |    33   | last_name |  Dirt      |

|    5     |    33   | first_name|  Joe       |

|    3     |    33  | points    |  800       |

And then a buddypress table with a similar structure.

|  id | field_id | user_id  | value |

|    1     |    1   | 20|  New York   |

|    2     |    2   | 20  | Blue      |

|    3     |    1   | 33    |  London    |

|    4     |    2   | 33  |  Red      |

The user_id field identifies the user and is the same across tables, but the tables do not reference each other.

So I am attempting to use this code

```
INSERT INTO new_table( user_id, last_name )
SELECT user_id, meta_value
FROM wp_usermeta
WHERE meta_key = 'last_name';

UPDATE new_table
SET first_name = wp_usermeta.meta_value
WHERE new_table.user_id = wp_usermeta.user_id
AND wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'first_name';
```

which returns " Unknown column 'wp_usermeta.user_id' in 'where clause'"

I have found suggestions about UPDATE saying to put quotes around the column. like

```
UPDATE new_table
SET first_name = "wp_usermeta.meta_value"
WHERE new_table.user_id = "wp_usermeta.user_id"
AND "wp_usermeta.meta_key" = 'first_name';
```

This will run without error, but the first_name column remains NULL.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Fixed by using a SELECT in my UPDATE statement (Set = SELECT)

Answer (score 0):

This fixed the issue.

```
UPDATE new_table as table
SET first_name = (
SELECT meta_value
FROM wp_usermeta
WHERE table.user_id = wp_usermeta.user_id
AND wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'first_name');
```